# Update the score when two turtles collide

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-3.7

1. I'm doing an assignment where I have to write a small game. When a turtle collides with a dot (bug) on the screen, it will add one point to the score value in the top left and teleport the bug to another random spot. I'm having trouble getting the score to update when they collide.
2. I tried to put the score update within the game loop but that did not work as it kept telling me that the value is not defined. I tried solving that with a global value, but that didn't do anything:

```
    import turtle
    import math
    import random

    #Set up the constants for the game.
    WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300
    WINDOW_WIDTH = 300
    FORWARD_STEP = 10       #how much does the turtle move forward
    TURN_STEP = 30          #how much does the turtle turn (in degrees)
    SHRINK_FACTOR = 0.95     #how much does the turtle shrink when it moves 
    DEATH_WIDTH = 0.05       #the size at which you stop the game because the user lost

    COLLISION_THRESHOLD = 10;#we say that two turtles collided if they are this much away
                            #from each other

    #Define functions

    def game_setup():
            '''set up the window for the game, a bug and the player turtle '''

            #create the screen
            wn = turtle.Screen()
            wn.screensize(WINDOW_HEIGHT,WINDOW_WIDTH)
            wn.bgcolor("light green")

            #Create player turtle
            player = turtle.Turtle()
            player.color("blue")
            player.shape("turtle")
            player.penup()
            player.setpos (random.randrange(1,301), random.randrange(1,301))

            #create a bug
            bug1 = turtle.Turtle()
            bug1.color("black")
            bug1.shape("circle")
            bug1.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.2, stretch_len=0.2)
            bug1.penup()
            bug1.speed(0) #the bug is not moving
            bug1.setposition(-200, 200)

            #create score turtle
            score_keeper = turtle.Turtle()
            score_keeper.hideturtle()
            score_keeper.penup()
            score_keeper.setposition (-400,360)
            score = 0
            scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
            score_keeper.write(scorestring, False, align="left", font=("Arial",14, "normal"))



            return (wn,player,bug1,score_keeper)

    def is_collision (player, bug1):
            distance = (math.sqrt((player.xcor()-bug1.xcor())**2 + (player.ycor() - bug1.ycor())**2))
            if distance < COLLISION_THRESHOLD:
                    return True
            else:
                    return False




    def main():


            #set up the window, player turtle and the bug
            (wn,player,bug1,score_keeper) = game_setup()

            #make the arrow keys move the player turtle
            bindKeyboard(player)

            #Set this veriableto True inside the loop below if you want the game to end.
            game_over = False

            player_width = get_width(player)

            #This is the main game loop - while the game is not over and the turtle is large enough print the width of the turtle
            #on the screen.
            while not game_over and player_width > DEATH_WIDTH:

                    #your collision detection should go here

                    if is_collision (player, bug1):
                            bug1.setpos (random.randrange(1,301), random.randrange(1,301))
                            player.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)



                    player_width = get_width(player)
                    player.showturtle()
                    print(player_width)

            print("Done")   
            wn.exitonclick()

    main()
```

3. This is most of the code. All I want it to do is when the `is_collision()` function happens, it adds 1 to the value of `score` and the `score_keeper` turtle then prints that value in the window.

Answer (score 0):

> Im havign trouble getting the score to update when they collide.

I've done a stripped down rework of your code below (substuting for methods you left out) to show how to update the score on the screen.  Code like this shouldn't have an explicit *main loop* as it's all event driven and should instead call turtle's main event loop:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randrange
from functools import partial

# Set up the constants for the game.
WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500, 500
FORWARD_STEP = 10  # how much does the turtle move forward
TURN_STEP = 30  # how much does the turtle turn (in degrees)
COLLISION_THRESHOLD = 10  # we say that two turtles collided if they are this much away from each other
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
FONT = ('Arial', 14, 'normal')

# Define functions

def is_collision(player, bug):
    return player.distance(bug) < COLLISION_THRESHOLD

def random_position(turtle):
    scale, _, _ = turtle.shapesize()
    radius = CURSOR_SIZE * scale
    return randrange(radius - WINDOW_WIDTH/2, WINDOW_WIDTH/2 - radius), randrange(radius - WINDOW_HEIGHT/2, WINDOW_HEIGHT/2 - radius)

def forward():
    global score

    player.forward(FORWARD_STEP)

    if is_collision(player, bug):
        bug.setposition(random_position(bug))

        score += 1
        score_keeper.clear()
        score_keeper.write(f"Score: {score}", font=FONT)

# Set up the window for the game, a bug and the player turtle.

# Create the screen
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
screen.bgcolor('light green')

# Create score turtle
score_keeper = Turtle(visible=False)
score_keeper.penup()
score_keeper.setposition(-230, 230)

score = 0
score_keeper.write(f"Score: {score}", font=FONT)

# Create a bug
bug = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
bug.shapesize(4 / CURSOR_SIZE)
bug.penup()
bug.setposition(random_position(bug))
bug.showturtle()

# Create player turtle
player = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
player.color('blue')
player.speed('fastest')
player.penup()
player.setposition(random_position(player))
player.showturtle()

# make the arrow keys move the player turtle
screen.onkey(partial(player.left, TURN_STEP), 'Left')
screen.onkey(partial(player.right, TURN_STEP), 'Right')
screen.onkey(forward, 'Up')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```